# Play store icon in App drawer disabled in Nexus 7

Tags: google-play-store, 4.1-jelly-bean, stock-android

i use the stock rom JB 4.1 on Nexus 7 8G.
There is a small play store icon in the top-right corner in app drawer(not app icons in ap drawer).

i found that the icon in my cm10 version phone and my friend's nexus 7 can be clicked and open play store directly, but mine wont work.
just as it is disabled.

why? how to enable it?

Comment: Seen this issue before, did you try rebooting your device?

Comment: @rnh16, thanks! i will try it later, and reply as soon as possible.

Comment: @rnh16, great, that works for me! will u post an answer and then i could mark it as the solution?

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From previous experience, rebooting the device should fix the issue.